# AngularJS: How can I use $index in onclick

Tags: angularjs, indexing, angularjs-ng-repeat

So, I'm using $index to create different ids for each radio button inside a ng-repeat. I'd like to reference those ids inside local events (not ng- events).

I made an example in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3MUlo5geHCuE071uXky1)

In this example, I'm using always the element radio3, but I'd like to reference the correct id for each name.

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in persons">
    <li onclick="$('#radio3').attr('checked', true);" ng-click="showIndex($index)">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio{{$index}}">{{person.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Can anybody help me to figure out how to do such thing?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. You have the index in your showIndex() event.  What sort of "local event" are you talking about? If you could add that to your plunker it would be helpful

Comment: onclick, for instance

Comment: Caught my breath now. `onclick` should just never be used, ever, in any code, Angular or not. Ditch that. Second, jQuery should hardly if ever be used with Angular. Ditch that, too. What you're left with, you can use to do something rational. This is nightmare code.

Comment: it is in the plunker... I'd like to manipulate the id name in my onclick so I could reference the correct id each line.

Comment: it's just a piece of code to explain what I need... is not real code... so... can you help or just talk about my code example?

Comment: your plunker works fine? it logs the index on click

Comment: Remove the onclick attribute and put the code 'angular.element('#radio3').attr('checked', true)' in the showIndex would be less confusing. Your plunker seems to works well.

Comment: I agree with @m59. It is unbelievably frustrating trying to help you shoot yourself in the foot. What you are doing most definitely goes against any good (forget best) practices, the $index thing will be the least of your worries. You hardly ever, if you use Angular correctly, need an `id`.

Comment: Ask about what you are trying to achieve with this approach in a broader sense. Are you trying to set an attribute of another element in response to a click? We will help you untangle yourself and set you on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `onclick` as it will hardly behave nicely, instead you need to do it *The Angular Way*™ using the built-in `ng-click` and `ng-checked`

```
<ul ng-repeat="person in persons">
  <li ng-click="person.checked = true; showIndex($index)" ng-checked="person.checked">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" ng-attr-id="radio{{$index}}">{{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

Note: If you do not want to edit the `persons` items, use some hashmap instead: `ng-click="selected[$index] = true"` and `ng-checked="selected[$index]"`

Comment: Thank you floribon... this actually helped.